# how to find polygon with given x and y coordinates

Tags: plsql

I have data like this, this is coordinates system of (x,y) pairs, so the question is how to get the (x,y) points that if we connect this points other points must be inside of polygon and it must be convex polygon

```
x_axis  y_axis  id
8        14.5    1
1.1      1.1     2 
3.5      3.4     3 
4.5      0.4     4
13.5     7.8     5
11.5     15.2    6
2.8      8.3     7
0.3      5.4     8
1.5      3.8     9
8        8       10
8.3      8.1     11
2        10      12 
5        14      13
...     ...     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution is to take the rectangle that contains all points:

```
select min(ap.x_axis) as x,
       min(ap.y_axis) as y,
       'lower_left' as desc
  from all_points ap
union all
select min(ap.x_axis) as x,
       max(ap.y_axis) as y,
       'upper_left' as desc
  from all_points ap
union all
select max(ap.x_axis) as x,
       max(ap.y_axis) as y,
       'upper_right' as desc
  from all_points ap
union all
select max(ap.x_axis) as x,
       min(ap.y_axis) as y,
       'lower_right' as desc
  from all_points ap
```

It is working solution for the problem you posted.

If you want 'the smallest' polygon, this is called 'convex hull'. The algorithm for finding it is called 'Graham scan' and it's descriped on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan).
We won't code it for you.